# HTMLCollection not counting right in editor? / for loop not working on elements in DOM

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, block-editor

I'm migrating my front-end code for a plugin to React and ESNext, and am still new to all of this, but for some reason, this really simple `for` loop isn't executing on the admin edit page, but is fine when viewing the post. The only thing I can see is that there seems to be a weird issue with how HTMLCollections are counted, on the back end. I have this code:

**EDIT**: *added the php back-end code that generates the `div` in question, and appended the full JS edit function.*

```
/*
 * external dependencies
 */
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

export default class App extends React.Component {
        render() {
                return (
                        <div className={"myapp-container"}>
                           // this is a test
                        </div>
                );
        }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
        let els = document.getElementsByClassName("myapp_wrapper_class");
        console.log("got elements ", els); // this fires fine, everywhere

        for (let el of els) {
                console.log("working with ", el); // this fires on the front-end, but not in the editor
                render(<App />, document.getElementById(el.id));
        }
});
```

When I look at the console, on the front end, it logs

```
got elements 
HTMLCollection (1) // note this "1"
0 <div id="myApp1" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;" class="myapp myapp_wrapper_class" data-cwragc-src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/nakaza.csv" data-cwragc-type="line"></div>
```

but in the editor, it logs

```
got elements 
HTMLCollection (0) // note this "0"
0 <div id="myApp1" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;" class="myapp myapp_wrapper_class" data-cwragc-src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/nakaza.csv" data-cwragc-type="line"></div>
```

I'm unsure whether that zero is the problem, but like I said, it's the only thing I can see that's weird. There are no error messages in the console. I *am sure* that the `for` loop isn't being executed on the back end, even though the element is there (as you can see in the console log), and exists in the rendered DOM.

The elements are created with a server-side render. In the block's edit function, it looks thusly (full source at end of post):

```
export function MyAppEdit( props ) {
//...
        const MyAppRender = () => {
                return(
                    <Disabled>
                        <ServerSideRender
                            block={ props.name }
                            attributes={{ ...attributes }} />
                    </Disabled>
                );
        }
//...
        return (
                <>
                        { controls }
                        <div { ...blockProps }>
                                { cwragcLocalFile && <MyAppRender /> }
                                { myAppPlaceholder }
                        </div>
                </>
        );
}
export default withNotices( MyAppEdit );
```

Grasping at straws, I also tried removing the `<Disabled>` wrapper on the editor side, but no change in effect.

The `div` in questions is rendered by the server-side render, which on the back end looks like this:

```
            // gutenberg editor specific functionality
            $this->loader->add_action( 'init',
                $plugin_admin, 'enqueue_gutenberg_scripts' );

    // in $plugin_admin
    public function enqueue_gutenberg_scripts() {
            $asset_file = include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ )
                . '../assets/js/myAppAdmin.asset.php');

            // register the compiled JS for the backend
            wp_register_script( $this->plugin_name . '-block-edit',
                plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )
                    . '../assets/js/myAppAdmin.js',
                $asset_file['dependencies'],
                $this->date_version(
                    '../assets/js/myAppAdmin.js')); //adds date stamp to version so we don't run into cacheing problems during development

            register_block_type( 'cwra-block/myblock',
                array(
                    'attributes' => array(
                        'cwragcBaseId' => array(
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'default' => 'myApp1'
                        ),
                        'cwragcLocalFile' => array (
                            'type' => 'string'
                        ),
                        'cwragcType' => array(
                            'type' => 'string',
                            'default' => 'line'
                        ),
                        'cwragcWidth' => array (
                            'type' => 'number'
                        )
                    ),
                    'editor_script' => $this->plugin_name . '-block-edit',
                    'render_callback' => array( $this->plugin_public,
                        'render')
            ) );
    }

   // now in $this->plugin_public
   public function render( $block_attributes, $content = '' ) {
            // if we don't have data, we can't do anything
            if ( ! array_key_exists('cwragcLocalFile',
                $block_attributes) ) {
                    return '<div id="'
                        . print_r($block_attributes["cwragcBaseId"], true)
                        . '_control_div" style="width: 100%; '
                        . 'min-height: 50px;" class="cwragc"></div>';
            }

            $controlEl = '<div id="'
                . print_r($block_attributes["cwragcBaseId"], true)
                . '_control_div" style="width: 100%; min-height: 50px;"'
                . ' class="cwragc cwragc_control '
                . ' cwragc_column_selector">'
                . '</div>';

            $mainEl = '<div id="'
                . print_r($block_attributes["cwragcBaseId"], true)
                . '" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;" ';

            $mainEl .= 'class="myapp myapp_wrapper_class"'
                . ' data-cwragc-src="'
                . print_r($block_attributes["cwragcLocalFile"], true)
                . '" data-cwragc-type="'
                . print_r($block_attributes["cwragcType"], true)
                . '"';

            $mainEl .= '></div>';

            $colSelectEl = '<div id="'
                . print_r($block_attributes["cwragcBaseId"], true)
                . '_col_control_div" style="min-height: 50px;"'
                . ' class="cwragc cwragc_control cwragc_col_control'
                . ' form-group">'
                . '</div>';

            $rangeSliderEl = '<div id="'
                . print_r($block_attributes["cwragcBaseId"], true)
                . '_range_control_div" style="min-height: 50px; display: none;"'
                . ' class="cwragc cwragc_control '
                . 'cwragc_range_control form-group">'
                . '</div>';

            $el = '<div id="'
                . print_r($block_attributes["cwragcBaseId"], true)
                . '_dashboard_div"'
                . ' class="cwragc cwragc_dashboard">'
                . '<div class="outer-wrapper">'
                . '<div class="app-body">'
                . '<div>'
                . '<div>' . $colSelectEl . $rangeSliderEl . '</div>'
                . '</div>'
                . '<div>'
                . '<div>'
                . $mainEl    // THIS IS THE DIV IN QUESTION
                . '</div>'
                . '</div>'
                . '<div>'
                . '<div>'
                . $controlEl
                . '</div>'
                . '</div>'
                . '</div>'
                . '</div>'
                . '</div>';

            $wrapper_attributes = get_block_wrapper_attributes();

            $el = sprintf('<figure %1$s>%2$s</figure>',
                $wrapper_attributes,
                $el);

            return $el;
    }
```

Basically, I have no idea what's going on here, but I'd like my stuff to render on the back end :)

Is it possibly a Babel bug? Is there some difference/timing/race issue with when `DOMContentLoaded` fires on the back end? Is there some better/more naturally React way for me to add a component to a `div` when I don't know how many of them there will be (other than `getElementsByClassName` after `DOMContentLoaded`?

For completeness' sake, my webpack is this:

```
const defaultConfig = require( '@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config' );
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    ...defaultConfig,
    entry: {
        myAppAdmin:
            path.resolve( process.cwd(), 'admin/src', 'index.js' ),
        myAppPublic:
            path.resolve( process.cwd(), 'public/src', 'index.js' ),
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve( process.cwd(), 'assets/js' ),
    },
}
```

Maybe I'm missing some other `require`? But, like I said, it's not generating any errors. `admin/src/index.js` is the block code; `public/src/index.js` is front-end code I'm trying to migrate, that adds React stuff after the server-side render.

---

full edit source

```
/**
 * WordPress dependencies
 */

import { isBlobURL } from '@wordpress/blob';
import { MediaPlaceholder, useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { Disabled, withNotices} from '@wordpress/components';
import { useDispatch } from '@wordpress/data';
import { useRef } from '@wordpress/element';
import { __ } from '@wordpress/i18n';
import ServerSideRender from '@wordpress/server-side-render';

export function MyAppEdit( props ) {
        const {
                attributes: {
                    cwragcBaseId,
                    cwragcLocalFile
                },
                attributes,
                clientId,
                noticeOperations,
                noticeUI,
                setAttributes,
        } = props;

        const ref = useRef();

        const { createErrorNotice } = useDispatch( 'core/notices' );

        // save the clientId as an attribute so we can use it on public side
        if ( ! cwragcBaseId ) {
                console.log('cwragcBaseId is ', cwragcBaseId);
                console.log('clientId is ', clientId);
                setAttributes( { cwragcBaseId: clientId } );
        }

        const MyAppRender = () => {
                return(
                    <Disabled>
                        <ServerSideRender
                            block={ props.name }
                            attributes={{ ...attributes }} />
                    </Disabled>
                );
        }

        function onSelectSrc( data ) {
                if ( ! data || ! data.url ) {
                        setAttributes( { cwragcLocalFile: undefined });
                        return;
                }

                if ( data.id || ! isBlobURL( data.url ) ) {
                        setAttributes( { cwragcLocalFile: data.url });
                        console.log('Set local file to ', data.url);
                        return;
                }

                console.log('Got file, ', data);
        }

        function onUploadError( message ) {
                noticeOperations.removeAllNotices();
                noticeOperations.createErrorNotice( message );
        }

        const chartPlaceholder = (
                <MediaPlaceholder
                    accept={ '.csv, .json' }
                    allowedTypes= { [ 'text/csv', 'application/json' ] }
                    icon={ 'chart-bar' }
                    labels={ {
                      title: "My Block",
                      instructions: __( 'Upload a data file, get one from a URL, '
                        + 'or schedule retrieval from a URL.', 'cwragc') }}
                    notices={ noticeUI }
                    onError={ onUploadError }
                    onSelect={ onSelectSrc }
                    disableMediaButtons={ cwragcLocalFile }
                />
        );

        const controls = (<></>);

        const blockProps = useBlockProps( {
                ref,
                className: "cwragc-block"
        } );

        return (
                <>
                        { controls }
                        <div { ...blockProps }>
                                { cwragcLocalFile && <MyAppRender /> }
                                { chartPlaceholder }
                        </div>
                </>
        );
}

export default withNotices( MyAppEdit );
```

Comment: The browser can't be wrong in counting the elements, so what component created that `myApp1` div? Or can we see your full (source) code? Also, Gutenberg has the [@wordpress/element package](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-element/), therefore you could just do something like `import { Component, render } from '@wordpress/element'` and then for example, do `class App extends Component`.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ; additional code added. Regarding `import { Component, render } from '@wordpress/element'`, can I do that on the front end? For some reason, I thought the @wordpress packages were only available in the block-editor (or at least only on the back end).

Comment: Ah sorry, I was focused on the `wp-admin`. But I'll check your code and hopefully I can suggest something...

Comment: So I've checked your code and I actually wanted to say this before, but I just wanted to confirm how you're creating the `myApp1` div. 1) Referring to that `HTMLCollection (0) // note this "0"` - the collection is actually indeed empty (try with `console.log( els.length )`), but the `0 <div id="myApp1"...`, i.e. the div you see there is actually evaluated after you called `console.log()` on the `els` - on Chrome, you'd see an "i" icon which would say, "Value below was evaluated just now.". See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44362860) for more details.

Comment: And 2) The `ServerSideRender` component uses the [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/rendered-blocks/) to fetch the rendered content, hence by the time the DOM is loaded, that content is not yet ready, which also the reason why the HTML collection is empty. So I hope that helps, but as for how to tackle the issue, I'm afraid you'll have to find it on your own.. :)

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ, I think this pointed me in the right direction. I got something working, and have asked about it [over here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/381877/194028). If people come back that there's no better way to do it, then I'll post it here as an answer. Can you take a look?